# what is the format of adobe swatch (ASE) file

Tags: android, android-studio, adobe

I have made an application in android that pick colors from camera and also from any image user pick.Now I want to export all that colors into Adobe Swatches.But the thing is I don't know the format of ASE. How we can export colors file to ASE file.I already exported into PNG .I have

`int colorcode=-23453123;
hashcode=#678945;
RGB=(123,56,67);`

From this How I can convert into ASE?

Comment: you can refer https://carl.camera/default.aspx?section=color for the format.